# GET http://localhost:3000/search 404 (Not Found)REACT.JS, Node.js and Axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

Can Anyone help me please?
I'm trying to build a youtube clone website, but I get this error:

GET http://localhost:3000/search 404 (Not Found)
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
at createError (createError.js:16:1)
at settle (settle.js:17:1)
at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (xhr.js:66:1)

App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import { SearchBar, VideoDetail } from "./components";

import youtube from "./api/youtube";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    video: [],
    selectedVideo: null,
  };
  handleSubmit = async (searchTerm) => {
    const response = await axios.get(""http://localhost:3000/search", youtube, {
      params: {
        part: "snippet",
        maxResults: 5,
        q: searchTerm,
      },
    });

    this.setState = {
      videos: response.data.items,
      selectedVideo: response.data.items[0],
    };
  };
  render() {
    const { selectedVideo } = this.state;
    return (
      <Grid justifyContent="center" container spacing={10}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Grid container spacing={10}>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <SearchBar onFormSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={8}>
              <VideoDetail video={selectedVideo} />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={4}>
              {/*VIDEO DETAILS */}
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

searchBar.js:

```
import React from "react";

import { Paper, TextField } from "@material-ui/core";

class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  state = {
    searchTerm: "",
  };

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ searchTerm: event.target.value });

    this.handleSubmit = (event) => {
      const { searchTerm } = this.state;
      const { onFormSubmit } = this.props;

      onFormSubmit(searchTerm);

      event.preventDefault();
    };
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Paper elevation={6} style={{ padding: "25px" }}>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <TextField
            fullWidth
            label="Search..."
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          ></TextField>
        </form>
      </Paper>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchBar;
```

youtube.js:

```
import axios from "axios";
const key = "MY_API_KEY";
export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://googleapis.com/youtube/v3",
});
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: Where is the code for your `/search` route on the server?

Comment: http://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3

Comment: Your answer is not logical. I asked for the code you wrote to serve the route `/search` on your backend that runs on localhost:3030 and you replied with a YouTube URL...?

Comment: Perhaps you meant to use `youtube.get('/search', ...)` instead of `axios.get('http://localhost:3030/search', youtube, ...)`? (If that's the case, then the next issue would be that you don't pass your API key as header.)

Answer (score -1):

This may help someone : **check the route in both ends (frontend and backen if they match)** for me just an _ caused me this error:
having **"/add_place"** in express, the call in react was **"/addplace"**